# Add parameters to nativetransition plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, telerik

I've just added the `NativeTransition` plugin to my `Ionic` app and I must say I'm very surprised with the actual result. 
http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/native-page-transitions

However, when clicking on an item it should direct to another page which uses the parameter to load the specific content.

The `state` url is as follows: `url: '/news/:newsId'`

The documentation says I need to use this line of code to make the transition work:

```
window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide({
    "href" : href
  });
```

My code:

```
$scope.showDetail = function (id) {
  window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide({
    "href" : '/news/' + id
  });
}
```

But it's not working, it does make the transition but it slides to the same page. Probably because the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` is triggered

Comment: I dont see options parameter in your sample code. Are you using global options? If not, is not manadatory in that case? Also are you getting any console error?

Comment: @Gandhi Updated my code

Comment: still don't see options argument in your code

Comment: Oh that parameter, it has the default settings if you don't include them. The slide works, it slides to the left. But I need to pass that URL query `id`

Comment: oh OK. Will dig deep and get back if I get some clue

Comment: Thanks, but I just found the problem. Quite stupid tbh

Comment: glad it worked. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I had to specify the URL starting from the root:

```
$scope.showDetail = function (id) {
  window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide(
    {
      "href" : '#/app/news/' + id
    },
    function (msg) {console.log("success: " + msg)},
    function (msg) {alert("error: " + msg)});
};
```